# Selenium send_keys does not send comma

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to use send keys like this

```
price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="contentproform-ppv_cost"]')
price.clear()
price.send_keys("12,99")
```

Which only results in sending 1299. I tried to paste it from the keyboard with the same result. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
This is the input tag:

```
<input type="number" id="contentproform-ppv_cost" class="form-control" name="ContentProForm[ppv_cost]" value="5.55" placeholder="Price for end-users" step="0.1" min="1.5" max="50" data-trigger="Input">
```

My workaround so far:

```
    price.send_keys("12")
    for i in range (9):
        price.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)
    price.send_keys("9")
```

EDIT2:
Using 12.99 also results in 1299

Comment: What's the input type for ```contentproform-ppv_cost``` ?

Comment: Can you share a link so we will be able to debug?

Comment: Is the input type `number` by any chance?

Comment: This is the element:
<input type="number" id="contentproform-ppv_cost" class="form-control" name="ContentProForm[ppv_cost]" value="5.55" placeholder="Price for end-users" step="0.1" min="1.5" max="50" data-trigger="Input">

It´s behind a login so there is no way for external users to debug it :/

Comment: If you are sending 12.99 and 12,99 and it is converting it to 1299, then I feel that there is a restriction like only being able to provide integers or something. This is not a webdriver issue, more likely to be a site issue.

Comment: The thing is that when I do it by hand it works with a ,

Comment: Any chance you can provide the site link ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It´s behind a login where registration is restricted

Answer (score 0):

This is less about Selenium and more about currency conversion in different countries. That website has JS that prevents invalid input for currency. There's a dot separator that's probably different from the country you're in. Here's the info from the web:

"United States (U.S.) currency is formatted with a decimal point (.) as a separator between the dollars and cents. Some countries use a comma (,) instead of a decimal to indicate that separation. In addition, while the U.S. and a number of other countries use a comma to separate thousands, some countries use a decimal point for this purpose."

I took a screenshot from Google. The full info was on the Cornell University site:

[image]

Comment: Yes I was aware of that. I tried to enter it with a . first but that also resulted in 1299 which is why I wanted to try a ,. I should have stated that in the question.